# How to detect if dual stack socket is supported?

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

It seems that dual stack sockets are not supported by some operating systems. I am looking for a reliable approach to detect if this feature is supported or not. My current suggestion (not tested yet) is checking the returned value of setsockopt to turn off IPV6_V6ONLY when I try to put the socket into dual stack mode. Do you think this works or there is a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: What are "all" platforms?  This functionality is not in standard C, so we need to be clear on what platforms need to work.

Comment: @Kaba, still not clear - for example, setsockopt does not exist on all platforms. The only way to cover ALL platforms is to read through the documentation of each OS with respect to the underlying hardware and find the way to do that.

Comment: @JohnZwinck The dual stack support verification part should work on Windows and POSIX OSes (including Unix, Mac OS X, Linux, Android and iOS)

Answer (score 2):

One approach that comes to my mind is to attempt to create an IPv6-only UDP socket and connect it to an IPv4-mapped address. This will not produce any actual network traffic, but by looking at the behavior of the code and the resulting local address assigned to the socket, you can figure out if the socket is actually IPv6-only.

Here is Python code demonstrating the idea. This can be directly mapped to equivalent C code performing the same sequence of system calls:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_V6ONLY, 1)
s.connect(('::ffff:169.254.1.1', 53))
print s.getsockname()
```

Possible outcomes:

1. `setsockopt` fails due to the `IPV6_V6ONLY` option not being supported.
2. `connect` fails due to socket being IPv6-only and connect recognizing that you are not allowed to bind such a socket to an IPv4-mapped address.
3. `connect` fails with no route to host. If that case you are left in the dark, because you don't know if it was looking for an IPv4 route or an IPv6 route, and you'd have to attempt connecting to other addresses to figure out which was the case.
4. `getsockname` returns an IPv4-mapped address, which means `IPV6_V6ONLY` and the socket is not IPv6-only.
5. `getsockname` returns an IPv6 address other than an IPv4-mapped address, which means the socket is IPv6-only and the code path used by connect had no clue that an IPv4-mapped address was somehow special.

I would consider it impossible to predict what quirks you could come across on various operating systems. But I am quite confident that the sequence of socket API calls I suggest would reveal any such quirks. So you'd have to test it on the target OS relevant to you to see how they each behave, and it may turn out a simplified version of the tests would be sufficient.